# ArcGIS Online Arcade Count Features

Tags: arcgis-online, count, arcade, arcgis-experience-builder, dashboard

I'm creating a dashboard using ArcGIS Experience Builder and I'm having trouble writing Arcade code to display the total number of assets with a condition equal to excellent.

[image]

I think I'm on the right track with code like

Count($feature.CONDITION = "EXCELLENT")

but, it doesn't work and I just can't fiqure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The [help file on Count()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#count2) says you need to feed into it a FeatureSet. It always pays to study the help file when calling functions to understand what they require and output they generate.

The code snippet below creates a FeatureSet using the [Filter()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#filter) function and that is passed into Count(), finally you return the result, in my case it was the pop-up for the test layer I  had created.

```js
var sQuery = "CONDITION = 'EXCELLENT'";
var fs = Filter($layer,sQuery);
var n = Count(fs);
return { type : 'text', text : "Number of excellent = " + Text(n)}
```